# Document ID URL opens excel File write locked

Tags: 2013, excel, document-id

We have some issues cause our users often are using the document id link. So when a document id link of an excel file will be opened the excel file is not editable. There's also no possibility to get this file editable. 
We also tried this with word or powerpoint files but these are opened in edit mode. 
Is there any solution to open excel files with the document id url in an editable mode?